# Would two million families lose their SNAP benefits under H.R.1947 (FARRM)? Why?

Tags: united-states, poverty

The [farm bill](http://www.trivalleycentral.com/maricopa_monitor/county_state/all-but-one-rep-from-ariz-opposes-farm-bill/article_631aa1a8-f09a-11e2-9cab-0019bb2963f4.html) has been passed in the House.

> The 216-208 vote largely followed party lines, with every Democrat voting against the bill and 12 Republicans breaking ranks to vote against it. [...]
>
> The bill came to the floor less than one day **after House leaders removed the Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program**, better known as food stamps.

The initial bill in June drew criticism from the [President](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/legislative/sap/113/saphr1947r_20130617.pdf)

> The Administration strongly opposes the harmful cuts to the Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program (SNAP), a cornerstone of our Nation's food assistance safety net. **The bill makes unacceptable deep cuts in SNAP, which could increase hunger among millions of Americans who are struggling to make ends meet**, including families with children and senior citizens.

and minority leader [Nanci Pelosi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTlZn9EdOOo)  ([transcript](http://www.democraticleader.gov/Transcript_of_Pelosi_Weekly_Press_Conference_on_Farm_Bill))

> But we do want a farm bill because we want to have in there the specialty crops, the fresh fruits and vegetables, the initiatives for food banks and the rest of that.  But you can't just keep cutting and cutting and cutting the nutrition program and expect people to swallow that, because the comments, you're taking food out of the mouths of babies.  **Two million families would lose their food under the bill, much less under the Southerland amendment.**

Would the [Southerland](http://www.govtrack.us/congress/votes/113-2013/h284) [Amendment](http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/bdquery/z?d113:HZ00231:) cause two million families to lose their Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program benefits? (How deep is this cut as a percentage of the whole?)

Why were they previously eligible, and why wouldn't they be under the Southerland Amendment?